# td em uma function

Tags: javascript

Tem a possibilidade de adicionar uma `td / div / table / iframe` dentro de uma function?

Por exemplo:

```
function Retorno(){
    <td height="#" width="#" >
        <div id="#" width="#">
            <table width="#">
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <iframe style="#" src="#" width="#" height="#" >
                        </iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
    </td>   
}
```

Para resumir, eu gostaria que fosse como o :

```
function Retorno(){
    window.self.location.href ="#";
}
```

Só que determinando tamanho, forma, etc.

Comment: Não entendi bem, a dúvida é como criar essa hierárquia DOM dentro de uma função? Para posteriormente adicionar ao DOM da página?

Comment: @Wakim, isso mesmo, é que no meu caso quero executar essa função chamando determinada página! Mas não tenho ideia de como colocar em javascript para digitar isso (nem sei se é possivel)!

Comment: Então você quer uma forma de alterar os valores dos elementos via javascript correto? Vejo duas formas de fazer isso, vou elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Wakim, obrigado ^^

Comment: @Felipe o mais prático pode ser ter esse código já no HTML com `display: none;` e fazer um clone quando precisar.

Comment: @Sergio poderia deixar mais específico ?

Comment: @Felipe se colocares esse html todo na  página podes ir buscar com javascript e fazer uma cópia e depois inserir onde for preciso. Pode ser util usar MooTools ou jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Uma possibilidade é guardar esse HTML como template dentro de uma tag `<script>`. O `type="text/template"` faz com que o conteúdo não seja interpretado como JS:

```
<script id="template-celula" type="text/template">
    <td height="#" width="#" >
        <div id="#" width="#">
            <table width="#">
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <iframe style="#" src="#" width="#" height="#" >
                        </iframe>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
    </td>   
</script>

<table><tr></tr></table>

<script>
function celula() {
     var html = document.getElementById('template-celula').innerHTML;
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.innerHTML = html;
     return div.firstChild.nextSibling;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].appendChild(celula());
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/zamefoba/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo a utilização do [Buildr](http://mlanza.github.io/buildr/).

```
var iFrames = [{
    width: "560",
    height: "315",
    src: "//www.youtube.com/embed/rj6OLq9W6RE",
    frameborder: 0,
    allowfullscreen: true
}];

$div = $("div");

function Retorno() {
    $div.build(function (b) {
        b.table(function () {
            b.each(iFrames, function (idx, it) {
                b.tr(
                b.td(
                b.iframe({
                    width: it.width,
                    height: it.height,
                    src: it.src,
                    frameborder: it.frameborder,
                    allowfullscreen: it.allowfullscreen
                })));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/Hym5Z/embedded/